# Something strange with my multitester

Tags: multimeter

I have a multi-tester. And its model name is J0411A. And it looks like this[image]You might see that this multi-tester includes a resistor tester. When I set the tester to x1 of Ohm section and connect + to - directly, I get about 2.6 Ohm. When I set the tester to x10(other things are same), it points 1.8 which it means 18 Ohm. Why two numbers are different?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Analog meters I've used had a "zero adjust" knob for setting the meter reading to zero when you short the leads.  This adjustment has to be made each time you change the scale.

Comment: But this option is not in this meter. @나진열 have you found this setting on your meter? Because I can't see it in the picture.

Comment: @WrichikBasu: The little knob immediately above the red lead is marked "0Ω", which should be a rather obvious clue!

Comment: @DaveTweed I couldn't read that. I thought that to be a fuse. Well, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @jsotola the question is **not** posted by me, neither do I have an analog multimeter, nor do I have any experience with one. I just commented based on the picture.